# Excel bad unicode characters

Tags: excel, encoding, character-encoding

I have an excel file with 25.000+ rows and 200+ columns.

through these cells there are many strings containing characters with broken unicode 
e.g `Avenue Gξ“Β©Nξ“Β©Ral-Guisan 38`

I do not have access to the original data. 
I tried to change file unicode and import/export to notepad++ instead of excel but i wan not lucky.

What I am looking for is a formula to indetify all cells with bad encoding.

Any ideas??

Thanks./

Comment: Look for cells that contain characters other then alfanumerical.

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding: you can use many encoding for unicode. The original name should be "Général", so it seems that é is translated to "ξ“Β©" (but why next letter is always upcase?). But looking the encoding, it seems encoded twice, and I do not understand what is original encoding. Greek? (8859-7), but the " is not correct (but excel mangle it). My tip: try to find an encoding which give you `Γ©` (copy the text, and try again with the same encoding) [possibly with a text export, and notepad++]

Comment: Is there any reason to think that all the data was not mangled by the same process? If not, once you find how to unmangle it (if possible), you can just apply it without having to figure out exactly where the bad effects of the mangling are.

Comment: `'ξ“Β©'.upper().encode('cp1253').decode().encode('cp1253').decode()` returns `'é'` (*triple* [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) found for @GiacomoCatenazzi)… (A [mcve] given here in Python)

Answer (score 0):

For others who come looking for an answer, this solved the problem for me (default Windows/ANSI US codepage):

Python POC only:

```
# convert 'Ã¢â‚¬Å“' into '“' etc
string.encode('cp1252').decode().encode('cp1252').decode()
```